# Why BluetoothSocket.getMaxReceivePacketSize() and BluetoothSocket.getMaxTransmitPacketSize() return 0?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I develop two apps which communicate via Classic Bluetooth - one as a client and the other as a server. I manage to perform successful connection and I want to optimize my read and write operations using BluetoothSocket methods - `getMaxReceivePacketSize()` and `getMaxTransmitPacketSize()` methods, but for some reason they both just return 0.
What might be the reason for that?
Thanks ahead.

Comment: Hi! I know you posted this long time ago. I'm having the same problem, so I use to set the buffer size to a default of 1024 bytes.